# What influence would a race of human gods with a lifespan in the tens of thousands of years and devoted to order have on human society?

Tags: magic, government

This idea came from an old video game called mortal kombat, which introduces a very long lived human race that existed in a realm bordering earth. The one it focuses on is a woman who is ten thousand years old, but is regarded as young by her people. Not much is expanded on their culture, and they seemed to be very "human like" for a people with their lifespan. So i tried to imagine what their society would be like.

Gods are vastly powerful beings that represent the pinnacle of the human race. They have a lifespan of 40,000 years and live in a parallel reality that exists side by side with the mortal realm. These gods adhere to a prime directive that was given to them by the universe, which is their creator. The directive tasks them with protecting humanity from threats originating outside reality. They retain their individualism, and have their own personality and egos. However, this directive is superimposed on them, as it is a part of their nature that they cannot turn against. It is helpful to think of them as sentient, self aware programs, or defense mechanisms of the universe itself. Gods view the universe as a larger cosmic entity that they are apart of rather than existing separately from it. They have emotions and experience their full range, but have evolved a very practical mindset. logical solutions take precedent in making decisions. While the gods "love" humanity, they tend to see them as a unit more than individuals, or as part of a bigger whole. This is due to their partial mindset and outlook on reality.

These gods are constantly at war with otherworldly creatures that exist outside of reality and threaten the mortal realm, such as demons, eldritch abominations, and the like. As such, their culture revolves around social order and cohesion, with everyone working towards a common goal. Males are usually the ones sent off to war and fight since they are more "expendable". Females are left behind to run things and keep the world functioning (making sure the sun rises and sets, seasons change, etc). God's don't breed very often, with a woman''s reproductive cycle taking place every 1000 years. They also don't interact with humanity very often, being busy defending it against enemies and running creation from behind the scenes, and seeing one is a big enough event in a human''s life to be memorable.

Included in the directive are a set of cosmic rules that a god abides by. These rules are meant to protect humans for abuse, but are left somewhat open-ended and flexible to situations.

1. Gods can't harm mortals, unless it's done for self-defence or the greater good (So they can smite a cult that wants to summon cosmic horrors, but can't destroy settlements because of a slight).
2. Gods must always act in the best interest of humanity and the material plane (adopting an utilitarian philosophy).
3. Gods are allowed to directly manifest on the material plane only if absolutely needed.
4. Granting powers and offering guidance to mortals is allowed, but only if these mortals act for the greater good.

Based on this setup, what influence would this race of God's have over humanity? How would they wield this influence?

Comment: How they interact with humanity is totally up to you. The premise and problems are very similar to [What sort of government might very long lived humans form with normal humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/what-sort-of-government-might-very-long-lived-humans-form-with-normal-humans). This question looks very opinion-based to me.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that there would be a necessary detachment, and no little amount sadness involved.

Imagine yourself in that position.  If you allowed yourself to care for something relative to your lifespan, lived a very short time, your heart would break.

I imagine that if a god allowed him or herself to become fond of a human, that god would try to keep a connection by caring about/for that one's descendants for at least a few generations.  Many gods, wanting their compatriots to spare their compatriots pain, would discourage such actions.

Eventually, the gods may write laws forbidding anything but platonic relations with humans, and limit even that.  This could end up causing harm if different gods came into conflict over different humans who's families they may have become involved with.

Think of the Greek myths about the Trojan War, where various gods took sides over loyalties or animosities they had towards the participants, and you'll see the reason for the necessary detachment.

The greek myths in general may prove good source material for this.

good luck

Comment: I can think of a handful of stories that touch on this, the ones most prominent in my memory at the moment is *We Are Legion: We Are Bob* and *Doctor Who.*

Answer (score 1):

You will find one very well worked answer in the works of JRR Tolkien, and particularly *The Lord of the Rings*. The Elves live thousands of years. Humans envy the Elves' long lives. The wisest or eldest of the Elves, might wish for human mortality, but mostly cannot.

I know this fantasy world is not a direct parallel to the questioner's one, but I've been more convinced by JRRT's working out of the psychology of the situation, than any other author. Arwen's choice and ultimate fate are particularly haunting.